# Get Cell Phone signal strength with No Listener

Tags: android, telephony

How do I just get the current CDMA signal strength without using a listener?
I do not need an update if the signal level changes.
Researching I dont see a solution yet. If it only reveals itself when it changes then how do the signal level bars on top work?  I just need a very rough estimate of cell signal strength related to the bars.

```
ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int CDMAdb=cm.SignalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with modem/RIL-related stuff, but since the phone will try to connect to a network when it starts I would guess that the status bar that shows the signal strength starts listening for signal strength changes immediately after boot.
 You can also do this by implementing a service that [starts automatically upon boot completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) and registers a `PhoneStateListener` that receives `onSignalStrengthsChanged` callbacks. The initial signal strength value before the first callback is received is up to you to decide (the minimum strength seems like a reasonable initial value).
Your activity can then query the service for the current signal strength (through an intent/binder/whatever) whenever it needs it.